# OverwriteModelError Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I seem to be getting an `OverwriteModelError` when using Mongoose to query.

I'm creating a Discord Bot where it will automatically update Player Titles on my Forums, however, when a Discord Players Role is changed it will log it to console but if the same player or a different player is then changed it throws this error

https://gyazo.com/2af4c0a967da3cf16b8157f8ca7abcbd.

This is the code that is being executed in my forumsUpdate.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const superagent = require("superagent");
const errors = require("../utils/errors.js");
const api = require("../utils/api.js");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
  updateUser: async (updateUserTag) => {
    try {
      const findUser = new mongoose.Schema({ discordUsername: String });
      const User = mongoose.model('players', findUser);

      const query = await User.find({ discordUsername: updateUserTag }).select('forums -_id');
      query instanceof mongoose.Query;
      const docs = await query;

      console.log(docs)
    } catch (ex) {
      return console.log(ex)
    }
  }
};
```

And that Function is called here in my index.js

```
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let updateUserID = (await bot.fetchUser(newMember));
    let updateUserTag = updateUserID.tag;

    forumsTitleUpdate.updateUser(updateUserTag);
})
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you try to update a User, you code calls `const findUser = new mongoose.Schema({ discordUsername: String });` which is not allowed.

Setup `Schema` outside `updateUser` method and it won't fail.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const findUser = new mongoose.Schema({ discordUsername: String });
```